# element inline background image override x2

Tags: css

I have element with background image defined:

```
<a href="#" style="background: url(img/slider-2.jpg) top left no-repeat;">
```

In the css I hide the background:

```
a {background: none !important;}
```

However, now adding in a some responsive design, I want to the background to show again.
Is there a way to point back to the defined style in the element?
I've tried manipulating, but nothing I do works.

```
a {background: transparent !important;} - didn't work
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using !important in your css? You should post more code so we can understand what you are doing / why you are using !important. From the code you posted, it looks like you are setting the background on all anchors. If you are using jQuery, you can set up a class for the transparent background and then add the class to the element when you want it and remove it when you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific in your media queries.  If you want to force `background:none` at X width but want it to show at XX smaller width, then you will need to specify that in the media query.  Lets say you want to hide the background between 1200 and 760 viewport widths (show at greater than 1200 and less than 760 but not in between).  Then you would need a compound media query like so:

```
@media (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    a {background: none !important;}
}
```

If you just want the image to display on small screen sizes, you could use `min-width` with the lower value.  Let's say you want it to show at or below 480 but not at any screen size larger than 480.  You would do the following.

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    a {background: none !important;}
}
```

If at all possible, try to not use inline styles.  It's a huge headache, but if you can't change that part of the code, using media queries will get you there.  More on media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the media queries, I was being to the point with my code. In your example, the 480 would be correct. the larger I would want to show the background. Since it's inline, is there a css trick that refers back to the inline code?

Comment: Unfortunately, no there is not.  The point of using the media queries is to not style at all (and by consequence allow for inline styling) at certain widths.  It can do what you are needing.  It's the difference between applying the style where needed and applying the style and then overriding it.  Overrides are great, but sometimes (such as with inline styles) it's not enough.

Comment: I'm trying to modify a slider and each slide has a different background. I'll keep playing. Thanks.